# How can I only ZIP certain types of files in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say that that I have the following files in a folder:

```
File1.txt
File2.py
File3.txt
```

I want to create a ZIP archive, but only of the .txt files. I could use a for loop to iterate through the files of this folder, like so:

```
for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk(path):
```

At this point, I'm not sure how I can efficiently filter out anything that isn't a .txt file. For this example, my first thought is to walk through the directory where my files are stored, and do something like this:

```
for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk(path):
    for i in files:
        if i == 'File1.txt' OR i == 'File3.txt':
            myZip.write(i)
```

I think this would work since these are the only files in the folder, but it wont work if there are more files in the folder. What's a better way to only write certain types of files to a ZIP archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the file name ends with `.txt`:

```py
for folder, subfolder, files in os.walk(path):
    for i in files:
        if i.endswith('.txt'):
            myZip.write(i)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Definitely gonna remember this for the future. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 0):

This is much simpler using `pathlib`, which provides recursive globbing.

```
from pathlib import Path


for f in Path(path).glob('**/*.txt'):
    myZip.write(f)
```